# Pass the image file on new Image

Tags: javascript, image, file, validation

So I have a file (uploaded using form) and I think the best way to validate if the image is an actual image is to actually create a new Image class of that file?

How can I make it so I can use the file to initiate a new image instance?

```
const fileFromForm = files[0];
const img = new Image();
const img.src = fileFromForm; // not sure if this will work ???
```

Comment: Note regarding the dupe: The accepted answer should not be used, it uses too much memory for nothing. Instead prefer the first solution described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27165977/3702797).

Comment: @Kaiido -san, but will this throw an error if the "url" or the file is a video? (I saw this answer earlier too but got confused)

Comment: Yes, to load a video, use <video> element. You can check the `file.type` to know which element to use